# Cookie expiry is different in browser and postman

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, cross-domain

No idea why this is happening we have an authentication cookie that is completely managed from the API server.

When I check the cookie expiry on the chrome browser it's showing the value which is completely different while checking the same cookie in postman client.

This request is actually a cross-domain request the only thing we made from the frontend(angular5 application) is to set this

```
headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
      }),
      withCredentials: true
```

Since we don't have the control over the backend API server I can't do any debugging on the backend

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Postman tries to set a default expiry date when there's no expiration date set on a cookie. Whereas a browser sets the expiration to `Session` when it receives a cookie with no expiration date.
This difference in behavior is what causes this.

You can try using Postman [Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) to make postman rely on browser for cookies.
You can learn about how to set it up [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/)